# .NET Web API project Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll

Tags: c#, .net

> Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll

I have a C# .Net project was running on .Net framework 4.6 **not .Net core**, but as required, we upgraded to 4.6.1. Then I can build successfully locally, but once I deploy my changes to VSTS, I got this issue from the build of DevOps. I'm using the latest version of VS, 2017 15.9.7

**Here is the detail of the error:**

> Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported:
>   'D:\a\1\s{ProjectName}\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue, when forgot to tick "Delete all existing files" checkbox before publishing. Enable it in publish profile settings.

[image]

Comment: So, have you resolved your issue after enabling "Delete all existing files"?

Comment: I haven't found where I can set it as "Delete all existing files" from Visual Studio. Can you tell me where can I config it?

Comment: Updated my answer with screenshot, so you can find where it is.